# preRemove never gets called as a doctrine event listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1, event-listener

I have an event subscriber, however the preRemove function is never getting called, but other event's are called. Is there anything that I did wrong?

```
class DocumentSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $serviceContainer;

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postUpdate',
            'preRemove',
        );
    }

    public function setServiceContainer($serviceContainer) {
        $this->serviceContainer = $serviceContainer;
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: have you registered the service as event subscriber?

Comment: yes... if you see above postUpdate works.. but not preRemove

Comment: preRemove works if you call $manager->remove($entity) method. If you call DELETE with a DQL statement it is not called. Do you call a DQL statement to remove the entity?

Comment: @KernelFolla how do I know which DQL statement is called to remove the entity?

Comment: just check if a query is executed, i think you are not deleting an entity. try with
    $manager->remove($entity);
    $manager->flush();

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour, but didn't found a solution ...